# Trying to understand the workflow for basic form validation using Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, validation

New to Spring here, and after reading the reference docs the workflow to validate a simple web form isn't popping out at me.

Could someone give me a beginners overview of how we go about form validation in Spring 3.0.3 (I'm using a mix of annotations and xml config in a webapp that I'm migrating now). Starting from the Controller, what happens?

For example: so far I think I understand that I should "bind" the form data to an object of my creation (say MyPerson for example), then create a Validation object that accepts MyPerson and uses ValidationUtils to perform the validation.

But that's all very fuzzy in my head (especially the "binding" concept) and a step by step review of the workflow from someone who's been through it before would help me be confident that I'm not missing or mis-interpreting any steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are mentioning for validating forms is one of a few options you have available.

As well as the method you have suggested you may also want to investigate using JSR-303 annotations with an appropriate implementation (for example Hibernate Validator). There are a lot of example of how to accomplish this.

For the spring validation method your basic steps are:

- Create an class to act as a binding object, pass an instance of this to the view in your controller
- Bind the object to the fields in your view using the form taglib
- In the controller method which handles the form submission, use the `@ModelAttribute` annotation to bind the form data to your binding object
- Use your custom validator object (probably `@Autowired` to your controller) to perform validation

Heres a simple example controller:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
```

```
@Autowired
private PersonValidator personValidator;

@RequestMapping(value="person/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView form() {
    // Instance of binding object
    Person person = new Person();

    // Create ModelAndView which displays personForm view
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("person/form");
    // Put our binding object in the model
    mav.getModel().put("person", person);

    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="person/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute Person person, BindingResult errors, Model model) {
    // Call our custom validator and put errors into BindingResult
    personValidator.validate(person, errors);

    // If we have validation errors
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        // Show form with errors
        return "person/form";
    }

    // Otherwise show some success page
    return "person/success";
 }
```

}

Comment: I guess something that is confusing me is where "@ModelAttribute Person person" is coming from? I'm using velocity, so can't use the JSP taglib (if that's doing it). Should I just be using @RequestParam("firstname")... @RequestParam("lastname")... as such and building a Person object in my controller? Then following the rest of the steps shown? Same question for BindingResult errors

Comment: Well I'm not aware of the specifics of how @ModelAttribute functions, and I'm not able to check right now, but I would guess that since the form JSP taglib outputs pure HTML, that there is something within the Spring framework itself that is responsible for the actual binding. The Spring documentation suggests there is some sort of Velocity binding macro available, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s04.html